# How to add an image to an existing facebook post using API and python?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I'm using [facebook graph API](https://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#put-object) to update/edit the text of a specific post on my page

```
import facebook

page_token = '...'
fb = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token = page_token, version="2.12")
page_id = '...'
post_id = '...'
fb.put_object(parent_object = page_id + '_' + post_id,
              connection_name = '',
              message = 'new text')
```

now I'm trying to add a local image (stored in the same folder of the python script) to this post but I don't understand how to properly do it, I tried

```
fb.put_object(parent_object=page_id+'_'+post_id, connection_name='', message='new text', source = open('out.png', 'rb'))
```

and

```
fb.put_object(parent_object=page_id+'_'+post_id, connection_name='', message='new text', object_attachment = open('out.png', 'rb'))
```

but none of them works. Hints?

p.s. these are the permission of my app

```
pages_show_list
pages_read_engagement
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement
```

---

EDIT: I tried with the function `put_photo` but it creates a new post adding the image to it, while I need to add an image to an already existing post

Comment: news: I tried with the function `put_photo` but it creates a new post adding the image to it, while I need to add an image to an already existing post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/

The Documentation states you can not perform updates.

[image: Here's A ScreenShot of The Same]

Comment: This is strange, I've just tried and I was able to delete an image. This is what I did: I manually created a post and added two images, then I got the ID of one of the two images and run the code `graph.delete_object(id=image_id)` and then the image got deleted.

Comment: Please Refer This Link https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/

Answer (score 1):

I made a complete selenium script in python which can handle the same task :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
import pyautogui as pag
option = Options()

option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

# Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
})

#########CHANGE################
EMAIL_ADDRESS="" # Email Address of your facebook account
PASSWORD="" # Password of your facebook account
POST_URL="" # URL of your post ex:- https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME/posts/ID
IMG_PATH="C:\\...\\test.jpg" # complete path of image
re_edit=True # set True when you already edited the post otherwise set it to False if you are editing the post for the first time
##########CHANGE###############

re_edit_val="/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]"
re_edit_val2="/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/span/div/div/div/div/div[1]"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option, executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
driver.set_window_position(-10000,0) # hiding the windows
print("Accessing facebook.com")
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
print("checking credentials")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='email']").send_keys(EMAIL_ADDRESS)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='pass']").send_keys(PASSWORD)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='pass']").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print("credentials checked successfully")
time.sleep(1)
print("Accessing the URL of the post")
driver.get(POST_URL)
time.sleep(0.5)
print("getting the edit access from facebook.com")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div").click()  # clicking three dots
time.sleep(3)
if re_edit:
     re_edit_val="/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]"
     re_edit_val2="/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/span/div/div/div/div/div[1]"
     
driver.find_element_by_xpath(re_edit_val).click() # clicking the edit post
time.sleep(3)
print("Uploading the given image...")
driver.find_element_by_xpath(re_edit_val2).click() # clicking Image upload
time.sleep(0.5)
pag.write(IMG_PATH) # uploading file path
pag.press('enter')
time.sleep(1.5)
print("Finishing up...")
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div")[0].click() # clicking save button
print("Photo uploaded")
```

All you need to do is to change the variables given above
Note:- It is working dated 9 Dec, 2020

Comment: thank you! i also did it with selenium but had to stop using it because sometime the window freezes and block the script, hence I'm looking for a way to do the job using the API, sorry for not being so clear in the question

Comment: @soundwave You should probably check what part of the script is causing the window to freeze. Also, there is no API for this purpose so it will be beneficial to use selenium. If you want to use an API then simply deploy my code to the Heroku platform and call an API request.